# I can not add a node in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file_data);
XmlNamespaceManager namespace_xml = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

//adicionar todos os namespaces necessarios
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> namespace_elem in all_namespaces)
{
    namespace_xml.AddNamespace(namespace_elem.Key, namespace_elem.Value);
}

XmlNodeList node_list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//w:tr//w:tc//w:p", namespace_xml);
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\}\}$");

for (int i = 0; i < node_list.Count; i++)
{
    XmlNode node_elem = node_list[i];
    Match mtch = rgx.Match(node_elem.InnerText);

    if (mtch.Success)
    {
        //caso seja uma linha que tenha de ser inserida
        XmlNode ancestor_node = null;
        XmlNode aux_node_elem = node_elem;

        while(aux_node_elem.ParentNode != null)
        {
            if (aux_node_elem.ParentNode.Name.Equals("w:tr"))
            {
                ancestor_node = aux_node_elem.ParentNode;
                break;
            }

            aux_node_elem = aux_node_elem.ParentNode;
        }

        ancestor_node.Clone();
        doc.Save(file_data);
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to find a node, in a XML file, whose text starts with "{{" and finishes with "}}" and duplicate his father. I can find that node but I can not duplicate his father. The following code is the XML that I want to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:tbl>
      <w:tblPr>
        <w:tblStyle w:val="GridTable4" />
        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1" />
      </w:tblPr>
      <w:tblGrid>
        <w:gridCol w:w="1698" />
        <w:gridCol w:w="1699" />
        <w:gridCol w:w="1699" />
        <w:gridCol w:w="1699" />
        <w:gridCol w:w="1699" />
      </w:tblGrid>
      <w:tr w:rsidR="0090425B" w:rsidTr="0090425B">
        <w:trPr>
          <w:cnfStyle w:val="100000000000" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0" />
        </w:trPr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:cnfStyle w:val="001000000000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0" />
            <w:tcW w:w="1698" w:type="dxa" />
          </w:tcPr>
          <w:p w:rsidR="0090425B" w:rsidRDefault="0090425B">
            <w:r>
              <w:t>Cabeçalho 1</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="1699" w:type="dxa" />
          </w:tcPr>
          <w:p w:rsidR="0090425B" w:rsidRDefault="0090425B">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:cnfStyle w:val="100000000000" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:oddVBand="0" w:evenVBand="0" w:oddHBand="0" w:evenHBand="0" w:firstRowFirstColumn="0" w:firstRowLastColumn="0" w:lastRowFirstColumn="0" w:lastRowLastColumn="0" />
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>Cabeçalho 2</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00163F00" w:rsidRDefault="00163F00">
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00163F00">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1701" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1701" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I try everything but I can not add a new node in the XML file. What did I make wrong?

Comment: You are cloning the node but not doing anything with it before you save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of `ancestor_node.Clone();`. It returns an `XmlNode`. Insert that one in the document again.

Comment: I forgot to insert in the document...-.-, but I tried to duplicate with this: `ancestor_node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(ancestor_node, ancestor_node)` and didn't insert in the document. Is this option also wrong?

Comment: You need to insert the clone, not the original., so it should be `ancestor_node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(clone, ancestor_node)`.

Comment: I only click in the up arrow